# php mail duplicates

Tags: php

Is there any reason why this would send duplicate emails?  I have a PHP page with only this code on it and every time I run it it sends me two emails.

```
<?php
    mail("abc@def.ghi", "test", "test");
?>
```

Comment: whats the full code? (did your refresh the page multiple times?)

Comment: this is the full code.  I had another longer form where I noticed the behavior and as a debugging test I just created a separate test.php script to see if mail() would work right just on it's own.

Nope, did not refresh twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the input.

As it turns out this was a browser plugin issue, specifically ySlow 2.1.0 on Firefox 4.0.1

I asked our server manager to look into the problem and he reported that the log was showing two hits every time I went to the page.  He tried loading it on his machine and the script worked properly and only loaded once.  I tried myself on Chrome and it worked, only emailing once.  I went through my various add-ons and finally isolated ySlow as the culprit.

Not sure if this means that ySlow is loading every page twice or what, but I'm going to have to keep it disabled.  If anyone has any suggestions about fixing the problem with ySlow, please let me know.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your page loads twice, therefore executes the code two times...You could try some limitation, something like that

```
if ($sent == '0') {
  mail("abc@def.ghi", "test", "test");
  $sent = 1;
}
```

Is this a simple php page, or part of a CMS? Maybe some modules might interfere with your page...

Comment: This is a simple php page, no CMS.

Comment: The page will always load twice and the post submit is not cleared.  Plus the $sent value, you suggest to define as 1, on a webpage will be cleared each time the page loads, so this code does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, I discovered my code had a command to spare and it generated two emails be sent:

```
<?php    
    $headers .= 'Bcc: anotheruser@domain.com' . "\r\n";
?>
```

I deleted this "\r\n" , it fixed the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but for those who are going to read this in the future:

Unset the post value after falling through the check for a submit, thus the reload does not process the data again:

```
if(isset($_POST[$SubmitCode]))
  {
  unset($_POST[$SubmitCode]);  // Clear post signal.
  }
```

When the page reloads, frequently the post submit setting is not cleared.  Why this is true I do not know, but clearing the post, solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to debug at this way

```
<?php
    mail("abc@def.ghi", "test", "test");
    exit("sent");
?>
```

simply put a 'exit' there and try again. If it still sent twice, maybe is the server problem or could be the [mail function] in ‘php.ini’ (sendmail_from & sendmail_path)

Comment: Tried this, it printed out sent, but I still got two email confirmations.  I also tried different email addresses, still the same problem. I'll look into the server settings.

Comment: sendmail_from = Local Value: no value, Master Value: no value.  sendmail_path = Local Value: /local/apache22/bin/phpmail-wrapper Master Value: /local/apache22/bin/phpmail-wrapper.  That looks pretty generic to me, do you see any problems?