# why this code adds two point every time that executes

Tags: php

why this code every time that executes adds two point to **number** in **a.txt** :

```
<?php

function substr_unicode($str, $s, $l = null) {
    return join("", array_slice( preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) , $s, $l) );
}

function statusRead() {
    $statusfile = file_get_contents('a.txt');

    // for detecting and removing BOM (0xEF,0xBB,0xBF)
    $statusfile = ord($statusfile[0]) == 239 ? ord($statusfile[1]) == 187 ? ord($statusfile[2]) == 191 ? substr_unicode($statusfile, 1) : $statusfile : $statusfile : $statusfile;

    $statusfile = str_replace("\r",'',$statusfile);
    $statusfile = explode("\n",$statusfile);
    foreach ($statusfile as $a) {
        $a = explode(":",$a);
        if($a[0]) $temp[$a[0]] = @$a[1] ? $a[1] : null;
    }
    return $temp; // changed: (($statusfile = $temp; return $statusfile;)) to ((return $temp;))
}

function statusUpdate($data) {
    $temp = '';
    foreach ($data as $a => $b) {
        $temp .= "$a:$b\r\n";
    }
    file_put_contents('a.txt', $temp);
}

$a = statusRead();
$a['number']++;
statusUpdate($a) ;
?>
```

this is content of **a.txt** :

```
stop:0    
number:5
dor:3
```

`a['number']++` every time adds two point to **number** in **a.txt** and when use `a['number'] += 2` adds 4 points to **number** in **a.txt**

**update:** I changed `$temp .= "$a:$b\r\n";` to `$temp .= "$a :$b\r\n";` and my data saved in this structure:

```
stop  :0    
number  :6
dor  :3
number :1
```

but why?

Comment: `$statusfile = $temp; return $statusfile;` <- you can simply `return $temp`.

Comment: this is not my problem. my problem is at saving!!

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You'll find that the `$temp` variable is not initialised in `statusRead()` which might affect your result. Fix the obvious errors and the weird ones might just go away.

Comment: I dont have any error in `statusRead()` section

Comment: I don't see a problem in the script, I suspect something is causing it to run twice.

Comment: @saeid do you really need to correct UTF chars ? can you post some example of what you have on the file ?

Comment: for now I havent any utf8 chars in that file but maybe add some persian chars to the file later

Comment: I checked **apache access logs** and saw that runs every script **twice**!!!  apache **mod rewrite** is not enable and I havent any **htaccess** file in my localhost directory. now what I must do?

Answer (score 0):

finaly my problem solved.

I had two extensions on chrome which is cousing this problem.

**1- Web Server Notifier**

**2- Web Technology Notifier**

after disabling these two extensions my problem solved.

I found my answer from this page:
[php mail duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268516/php-mail-duplicates)