# why this code save file data in wrong structure? php

Tags: php, save

I have this code:

```
<?php
$a = file_get_contents('a.txt');
$a .= "test2\r\n";
file_put_contents('a.txt', $a);
var_dump( file_get_contents('a.txt')) ;
?>
```

and this is content of **a.txt** before executing the code:

```
test1
```

when run it this result showed to me in browser:

```
string 'test1
test2
' (length=14)
```

but when I open the **a.txt** by notepad I saw this content:

```
test1
test2
test2
```

and when I execute code again it saw this result in browser:

```
string 'test1
test2
test2
test2
' (length=28)
```

but content of **a.txt** after execute was this in notepad:

```
test1
test2
test2
test2
test2
```

but why?

I asked a similar question at *[why this code adds two point every time that executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757744/why-this-code-adds-two-point-every-time-that-executes)* but no one answered a good answer to me :((

Comment: I don't experience this behavior when I run the code. If I run the code once, it shows me test1 test2 in the browser, and then when I open it up in the file, it also shows me test1 and test2. If I run it again, I see test1 test2 test2 in both the browser and the file. 

So if your question is "why is test2 being appended twice in the file but only once in the browser", I don't know if I can answer that question without more details about what you're trying to achieve. It could also be that I'm on Windows, and you're on a different environment.

Comment: I don't agree with you, I tested your code and It shows exactly what saved in the a.txt

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your file, I tested your script and got exactly what I expected to find.

Comment: Maybe you accidently hit the browser refresh button **twice** or your mouse is "double-clicking" with one click. Faulty mouse? Dunno man.

Comment: my os is windows xp and use wamp v2.2 and have problem with this code. I tested this code on windows server 2003 with wamp v2.0 and there had problem with this code too

Comment: I checked **apache access logs** and saw that runs every script **twice**!!!  apache **mod rewrite** is not enable and I havent any **htaccess** file in my localhost directory. now what I must do?

Answer (score 1):

You are always appending `test2\r\n` to what's already in the file.

Comment: I think his concern is that what is showing in the browser is different than what's showing in the file. Though when I ran his code, I did not experience this problem.

Comment: **file_put_contents** with **FILE_APPEND** flag must append data to rest of file and without **FILE_APPEND** must clear data and then append data to the file.

Comment: @saeid If you read the code you can see that he reads in the file as a string, appends his text, then writes it back to the file. Essentially the same as using `FILE_APPEND`.

Comment: @Rob if I use `FILE_APPEND` in first execute my result is this: `test1test1test2
test1test1test2
test2`
but it must have this result: `test1test1 test2`

Answer (score 0):

finaly my problem solved.

I had two extensions on chrome which is cousing this problem.

**1- Web Server Notifier**

**2- Web Technology Notifier**

after disabling these two extensions my problem solved.

I found my answer from this page:
[php mail duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268516/php-mail-duplicates)